# How to find covariance between two series?

Tags: python, r, pandas, covariance

If I do `cov(RM,stocksRetData[[1]]$Ret)` in R i get a different value compared to if I do
`RM.cov(d['Ret'])` in python even though both the series have same data.

Why is this?

If I do `var(RM)` and `RM.var()` they both return same value in R and python respectively.

Similarly if I do `var(stocksRetData[[1]]$Ret)` and `d['Ret'].var()` they both return same value in R and python

Comment: Do you have the same index in `DM` and `d`? Can you try `RM.cov(d['Ret'].values)`? Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @mozway if I do that I get typeError unsupported type class numpy.darray

Comment: All of the duplicates I linked are about numpy but pandas cov functions call the numpy functions. There's a bunch of details about the differences between how python covariance is implemented vs R. Also the differences between cov and var because of the difference if default ddof.

Comment: @HenryEcker yeah the linked questions are talking about numpy.cov while I am using python cov

Comment: As I stated above. `pandas` `cov` calls `np.cov`. [Source code for DataFrame.cov](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L9521)

Comment: @HenryEcker but if I pass rowvar = False in cov it gives me error. What should I pass for the same effect?

Comment: `RM.cov(d['Ret'], ddof=0)` would be my guess it's hard to say for sure without sample data and expected output.

Comment: @HenryEcker I tried that but it returns same value as it was returning without ddof=0

Comment: Again. It's hard to say without sample data, or expected output.

Answer (score 1):

For Series in pandas, you can use the method cov()  [cov documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cov.html),
and here is the implementation

```
s1 = pd.Series([0.90010907, 0.13484424, 0.62036035])
s1.var()
0.14993591657434988
s2 = pd.Series([0.12528585, 0.26962463, 0.51111198])
s2.var()
0.03800193770211464
s1.cov(s2)
-0.01685762652715874
```